# how to replace commented line with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I want to replace below line with sed so I am trying below command which is giving me error "sed: -e expression #1, char 59: unknown option to `s'"

I have not known to sed much can you guys help what I am missing in below command

```
sed -i 's/"\#trusted_proxies = "/"trusted_proxies = 172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12, 172.18.0.0/12, 172.19.0.0/12 "/g' runup.sh
```

it is giving "sed: -e expression #1, char 59: unknown option to `s'" error.

Regards,
SAMURAI

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `/` characters in your replacement text and you're also using `/` as your sed delimiter. Try using a different character as your sed delimiter, like `:`:

```bsh
sed -i 's:"\#trusted_proxies = ":"trusted_proxies = 172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12, 172.18.0.0/12, 172.19.0.0/12 ":g' runup.sh
```